# Multer with Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am having some issue with using `Multer` with `express.js`. So this works fine:

```
const multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file)
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
});
```

But when I try to do it like this, `req.file is undefined`:

```
const multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});
router.route('/', upload.single('image'))
    .post(function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.file);
        let memory = new Memory();
        Object.assign(memory, req.body);
        memory.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({message: 'Memory Created', memory});
        });
    })
```

Just wondering if what the correct syntax would be if I want to seperate my `routes.js` from my `server.js`.

I also tried this:

```
const multer = require('multer');
let upload = multer({dest: 'uploads/'});
router.route('/')
    .post(upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.file);
        let memory = new Memory();
        Object.assign(memory, req.body);
        memory.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({message: 'Memory Created', memory});
        });
    })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.file);

    // Do something with the file
});
```

Make sure that the post request body has the file attached to the `image` property. If you are using Postman to test, it should be something like this:

[image]